# PHP - Should a prepared statement be used?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following query

```
UPDATE users SET 
    username = CASE userid WHEN '1' THEN 'user1' WHEN '2' THEN 'user2' END, 
    email = CASE userid WHEN '2' THEN 'xyz@abc.com' WHEN '2' THEN 'pqr@xyz.com' END
WHERE userid IN ('1','2');
```

Will using a prepared statement be better if I have tons of `userid`?

How will the prepared statement for this query look like? (There are more fields besides username and email, so it should be generic)

Will it be something like

```
$stmt->prepare('UPDATE users SET username = ?, email = ? WHERE userid = ?');
```

and bind and execute that statement in a loop for all values in the array?

> **My query was generated using loops running through an array of values**

Comment: prepared statments makes sence, if you use parameter in your query. Not if you use constant values

Comment: A prepared statement or a parameterized statement is used to execute the same statement repeatedly with high efficiency.

Comment: @Blueblazer172 and to prevent sql injection

Comment: @Hopper exactly

Comment: @exactly what you said in now deleted comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Definitely it will make your code more clear and also will spare the SQL server from parsing such a big query.

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET username = ?,  email = ? WHERE userid = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $email, $userid);
foreach ($whatever as $row)
{
    $username = $row['username'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $userid = $row['userid'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```